# Kubernetes - force restarting on specific memory usage

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, kubernetes-pod

our server running using Kubernetes for auto-scaling and we use newRelic for observability
but we face some issues

1- we need to restart pods when memory usage reaches 1G it automatically restarts when it reaches 1.2G but everything goes slowly.

2- terminate pods when there no requests to the server

my configuration

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: {{ .Release.Name }}
  labels:
    app: {{ .Release.Name }}
spec:
  revisionHistoryLimit: 2
  replicas: {{ .Values.replicas }}
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: {{ .Release.Name }}
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: {{ .Release.Name }}
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: {{ .Release.Name }}
          image: "{{ .Values.imageRepository }}:{{ .Values.tag }}"
          env:
            {{- include "api.env" . | nindent 12 }}
          resources:
            limits:
              memory: {{ .Values.memoryLimit }}
              cpu: {{ .Values.cpuLimit }}
            requests:
              memory: {{ .Values.memoryRequest }}
              cpu: {{ .Values.cpuRequest }}
      imagePullSecrets:
        - name: {{ .Values.imagePullSecret }}      
      {{- if .Values.tolerations }}
      tolerations:
{{ toYaml .Values.tolerations | indent 8 }}
      {{- end }}
      {{- if .Values.nodeSelector }}
      nodeSelector:
{{ toYaml .Values.nodeSelector | indent 8 }}
      {{- end }}
```

my values file

```
memoryLimit: "2Gi"
cpuLimit: "1.0"
memoryRequest: "1.0Gi"
cpuRequest: "0.75"
```

thats what I am trying to approach

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to be sure your pod/deployment won't consume more than `1.0Gi` of memory then setting that `MemoryLimit` will do job just fine.

Once you set that limits and your container exceed it it becomes a potential candidate for termination. If it continues to consume memory beyond its limit, the Container will be terminated. If a terminated Container can be restarted, kubelet restarts it, as with any other type of runtime container failure.

For more readying please visit section [exceeding a container's memory limit](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/assign-memory-resource/#exceed-a-container-s-memory-limit)

Moving on if you wish to scale your deployment based on requests you would require to have custom metrics to be provided by external adapter such as [prometheus](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/prometheus-adapter). Horizontal pod autoascaler natively provides you scaling based only on CPU and Memory (based on the metrics from metrics server).

The adapter documents provides you [walkthrough](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/prometheus-adapter/blob/master/docs/walkthrough.md) how to configure it with Kubernetes API and HPA.  The list of other adapters can be found [here](https://github.com/kubernetes/metrics/blob/master/IMPLEMENTATIONS.md).

Then you can scale your deployment based on the `http_requests` metric as showed [here](https://github.com/stefanprodan/k8s-prom-hpa#auto-scaling-based-on-custom-metrics) or `request-per-seconds` as described [here](https://www.weave.works/blog/kubernetes-horizontal-pod-autoscaler-and-prometheus).

Comment: I would like to assign 2G for each pod but force termination when memory usage to 1G is that possible?